# Discord Python bot - Coroutine never awaited

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, discord, bots

I'm trying to make a Blind-test bot game in Python, which actually works pretty fine. I managed to get a whole spotify playlist in the queue with that `play_next()` function.

```
def play_next(ctx):

    if len(song_queue) >= 1:
        del song_queue[0]
        source = song_queue[0]
        vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source.preview_url),
            after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
        track_played = source

@client.command()
async def start(ctx):
    ...
    ...
    for song in tracks:
        if not song.track.preview_url:
            continue
        source = song.track
        song_queue.append(source)
        if not vc.is_playing():
            vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source.preview_url),
                after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
            track_played = source
```

As soon I turn the `play_next()` function to `async` to output details about the tracks being played, problems start.

```
async def play_next(ctx):

    await ctx.send("The answer was: {} from {}".format(track_played.name,
        ' and'.join(track_played.artists)))
    if len(song_queue) >= 1:
        del song_queue[0]
        source = song_queue[0]
        await ctx.send('Next song is about to start')
        vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source.preview_url),
            after=lambda e: play_next(ctx))
        track_played = source
```

Running the previous code throws me this error:

> play_next() was never awaited

How can I solve this?

Comment: no need for global loop, get_event_loop() should return the default loop, you can also use preferable get_running_loop() if youre sure that there is an event loop running, also, once you turn play_next() in async you need to put an await when calling it, which seems to be what were missing before

Comment: Thanks for your advice @geckos, I'll look into it! `lambda x: await play_next(ctx)` was throwing this kind of error: `await outside a asynchronous function`, and I definitely turned it upside down and found no way to make it work that way. I maybe missed something here thb

Comment: Making things async is not always trivial since everything down stack need to be async too :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Note: this answer was originally added in [Revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/63838824/3) of the question.)*

---

I finally came across a solution, which I honestly don't know if it's safe or if it is good practice.

I had to leave that `play_next()` function synchronous, and get the calls to `ctx.send()` in another `async` function, as follows:

```
async def sendMsg(message, ctx):
    await ctx.send(message)
```

and use asyncio to call the coroutine in the main loop thread. See:

```
def play_next(ctx):
    ...
    send_fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sendMsg(message, ctx), loop)
    send_fut.result()
    if len(song_queue) >= 1:
        source = song_queue[0]
        message = ('Next song is about to start')
        send_fut = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(sendMsg(message, ctx), loop)
        send_fut.result()
        del song_queue[0]
        track_played = source
        vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(source=source.preview_url),
                after=lambda x: play_next(ctx))
```

Having previously initialised `loop` in the `main()` with a global variable. Note that I struggled a lot with those two lines as I tried numerous orders and places before finding the right one. Alose note the `get_event_loop()` instead of `new_event_loop()`.

```
def main():
    global loop

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    def_globals()
    client.run('TOKEN')
```